# Why can't a global component be separated from a Vue instance into a different JS file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

### global.js

```
var app;
app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        value: "hello world",
    }
});`
```

### login.js

```
Vue.component('login', {
   template: '<h1>login</h1>'
})
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Daemon</title>
   <script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
   <script src="./js/semantic.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
   <script src="./js/vue.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/semantic.min.css"> </head> <body>
   <div id="app">
       <div class="ui container">
           <div class="ui divider"></div>
           <div class="ui blue button">
               {{value}}
           </div>
           <login></login>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script src="./js/global.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
   <script src="./js/login.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I get an error like this: `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <login> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.(found in <Root>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the `login` component first before you use it in the template of another component.

Order your scripts like this:

```
<script src="./js/login.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="./js/global.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```